# Create a tab system with html data attribute and jquery based on the value of the data

Tags: jquery, html, attr, custom-data-attribute

I'm in the process of improving my jquery skills.

Here's my problem:

I'm creating a tab system with jquery and in my HTML I added the data attribute both to my order list and to my tab selected:

```js
let tabHeader = $('.x-nav-tabs-item');
let tabContent = $('.x-tab-pane');
let attributevalue = tabContent.attr('data-cs-tab-index');

tabHeader.click(function() {
  tabHeader.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  let match1 = $('.active a').attr('data-cs-tab-toggle');
  tabContent.removeClass('active');
  console.log(match1);

  tabContent.attr('data-cs-tab-index').val(match1).addClass(active);
});
```

```html
<ul class="x-nav" data-x-element="tab_nav" data-x-params="orientation-horizontal">
 <li class="x-nav-tabs-item">
  <a data-cs-tab-toggle="1">For High school graduates (under 19 yrs):</a>
 </li>
 <li class="x-nav-tabs-item active">
  <a data-cs-tab-toggle="2">For Mature Students (19 years+):</a>
 </li>
 <li class="x-nav-tabs-item">
  <a data-cs-tab-toggle="3">For LPNs applying for the RDPN Access program:</a>
 </li>
</ul>


<div class="x-tab-content">
 <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="1">
  <ul>
   <li>Graduation from Grade 12 with a C+ average</li>
   <li>Grade 12 English (minimum grade B)*</li>
   <li>Grade 12 Biology (minimum grade C)</li>
   <li>Grade 11 Math (Foundations, Principles or Precalculus – minimum grade C)</li>
   <li>Grade 10 Science (minimum grade C)</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="2">
  <ul>
   <li>Grade 12 English (minimum grade B)*</li>
   <li>Grade 12 Biology (minimum grade C)</li>
   <li>Grade 11 Math (Foundations, Principles or Precaculus – minimum grade C)</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="3">
  <ul>
   <li>Copy of Licensing as Practical Nurse</li>
   <li>Proof of the equivalent of 2 years (3600 hours) full-time Work Experience as an LPN</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
</div>
```

That could be one idea on how to tackle the problem. It doesn't work of course, I'm thinking about the data() function to retrieve the value with a different approach like:

```
tabContent.each(function() {
  let value = $(this).data('cs-tab-index');
  console.log(value);
  if (value == match1) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
});
```

Or a script like:

```
tabContent.removeClass('active');
tabContent.data('cs-tab-index').val(1).addClass('active');
```

Both of them don't work.

Any suggestion or someone who could point out where my mistake is?

Comment: what is the issue?

Comment: It doesn't work. I need that, when I click the first tab with the value of 1 it has to add the class active to the match data attribute to the second list

Comment: Based on the click of the `<div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="1">` should it be triggered?

Comment: yes, they are connected

Comment: "*I'm in the process of improving my jquery skills.*" - indent your js code - life will be so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):**

```js
let tabHeader = $('.x-nav-tabs-item');
let tabContent = $('.x-tab-pane');
let attributevalue = tabContent.attr('data-cs-tab-index');

tabHeader.click(function() {
  tabHeader.removeClass('active');
  tabContent.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  let match1 = $('.active a').attr('data-cs-tab-toggle');

  $(`.x-tab-pane[data-cs-tab-index="${match1}"]`).toggleClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="x-nav" data-x-element="tab_nav" data-x-params="orientation-horizontal">
  <li class="x-nav-tabs-item">
    <a data-cs-tab-toggle="1">For High school graduates (under 19 yrs):</a>
  </li>
  <li class="x-nav-tabs-item active">
    <a data-cs-tab-toggle="2">For Mature Students (19 years+):</a>
  </li>
  <li class="x-nav-tabs-item">
    <a data-cs-tab-toggle="3">For LPNs applying for the RDPN Access program:</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="x-tab-content">
  <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="1">
    <ul>
      <li>Graduation from Grade 12 with a C+ average</li>
      <li>Grade 12 English (minimum grade B)*</li>
      <li>Grade 12 Biology (minimum grade C)</li>
      <li>Grade 11 Math (Foundations, Principles or Precalculus – minimum grade C)</li>
      <li>Grade 10 Science (minimum grade C)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="2">
    <ul>
      <li>Grade 12 English (minimum grade B)*</li>
      <li>Grade 12 Biology (minimum grade C)</li>
      <li>Grade 11 Math (Foundations, Principles or Precaculus – minimum grade C)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="3">
    <ul>
      <li>Copy of Licensing as Practical Nurse</li>
      <li>Proof of the equivalent of 2 years (3600 hours) full-time Work Experience as an LPN</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is something like:

```
$('.x-nav a').on('click', function() {
    $('.x-tab-pane')
        .hide()
        .filter('[data-cs-tab-index=' + $(this).attr('data-cs-tab-toggle') + ']')
        .show();
});
```

And [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8Lpjcxhy/) is a demo

Answer (score 1):

You're not far off.  This line:

```
 tabContent.attr('data-cs-tab-index').val(match1).addClass(active);
```

is a little confused and should be:

```
 tabContent.filter('[data-cs-tab-index=' + match1 + ']').addClass("active");
```

which is find, within `tabContent`, the node that has `data-cs-tab-index` matching `match1`.   There are other ways to do this, such as using map.

Without making too many changes to your existing code, here's an updated version:

```js
let tabHeader = $('.x-nav-tabs-item');
let tabContent = $('.x-tab-pane');

tabHeader.click(function() {
  tabHeader.removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
  
  //let match1 = $('.active a').data('cs-tab-toggle');
  let match1 = $(this).find("a").data('cs-tab-toggle');
  
  tabContent.removeClass('active');
  tabContent.filter('[data-cs-tab-index=' + match1 + ']').addClass("active");  
});
```

```css
.x-tab-pane { display:none; }
.x-tab-pane.active {
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="x-nav" data-x-element="tab_nav" data-x-params="orientation-horizontal">
  <li class="x-nav-tabs-item">
    <a data-cs-tab-toggle="1">For High school graduates (under 19 yrs):</a>
  </li>
  <li class="x-nav-tabs-item active">
    <a data-cs-tab-toggle="2">For Mature Students (19 years+):</a>
  </li>
  <li class="x-nav-tabs-item">
    <a data-cs-tab-toggle="3">For LPNs applying for the RDPN Access program:</a>
  </li>
</ul>


<div class="x-tab-content">
  <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="1">
    <ul>
      <li>Graduation from Grade 12 with a C+ average</li>
      <li>Grade 12 English (minimum grade B)*</li>
      <li>Grade 12 Biology (minimum grade C)</li>
      <li>Grade 11 Math (Foundations, Principles or Precalculus – minimum grade C)</li>
      <li>Grade 10 Science (minimum grade C)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="2">
    <ul>
      <li>Grade 12 English (minimum grade B)*</li>
      <li>Grade 12 Biology (minimum grade C)</li>
      <li>Grade 11 Math (Foundations, Principles or Precaculus – minimum grade C)</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="x-tab-pane" data-cs-tab-index="3">
    <ul>
      <li>Copy of Licensing as Practical Nurse</li>
      <li>Proof of the equivalent of 2 years (3600 hours) full-time Work Experience as an LPN</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```